# Why does the frequency of a composite particle scale with its mass?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, frequency

The wave frequency of a particle is equal to $\frac{mc^2}{h}$, which I get for fundamental particles, but how does this work for composite particles? The wavefunction now has axes for several particles with their own frequencies that aren't necessarily the same. Does it have anything to do with the fact that the frequency of the product of rotating complex numbers is equal to the sum of their frequencies? Is that the whole explanation?

Comment: 1. By "wave frequency" do you mean the frequency corresponding to the deBroglie wavelength? 2. At scales at which you can meaningfully treat the composite particle as a particle and not as a complicated state of its constituents (compare the low energy proton to the parton sea we have to use in colliders), why would it matter that its composite?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. Is this basically asking "why should anyone care?"?

Comment: No, I mean why would you want to argue from the constituents here - in a situation where it matters that a particle is made of constituents, it's typically not a good idea to treat it as just a single particle at all. The deBroglie wavelength is just a heuristic to assign a wavelength to a freely propagating quantum object, it's not an axiom of QM or a physical law or anything.

Comment: What is your background in QM? Have you taken a course (or courses) in it? That would help in tailoring an answer.

Comment: @J.Murray I haven't taken any courses, but I've done a decent amount of research. Looking at my other questions may give you a better idea of where I'm at.

Comment: This question is most unclear.  Maybe the OP can clarify a refinement to @J.Murray ‘s question: how much is a “decent amount” and what does “research” mean in “a decent amount of research”?

Answer (score 0):

Once more , the **wave**  when modeling the behavior of a quantum mechanical particle, is not modeling the particle in space , but the **probability** of finding the particle at a particular (x,y,z,t) in spacetime.

The correct mathematical modeling has to go through the solution of the quantum mechanical  wave equation for the particular set up, with the particular boundary conditions, and use those solutions to calculate the probability  .

The heuristic  deBroglie wavelength or the Heisenberg uncertainty principle are envelopes of this probability behavior at the quantum level. They are still useful because they allow estimates for the statistical behavior of particles when interacting with bulk matter.

> The wave frequency of a particle is equal to $mc^2/h$,

You are talking of the de Broglie frequency , [when the particle is at rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#Special_relativity).

As far as the mathematics goes the formula can be applied for any mass because it is the relativistic invariant mass, so a composite particle has a fixed invariant mass given by the length of the  summed [four vector of all](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) the components. [Here is the derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#Special_relativity),

[image]

For a particle at rest, $v=0$ one gets your formula.

So it is the four vector algebra used in the formula that allows no difference between fundamental and composite particles in their statistical quantum mechanical wave behavior described by the deBroglie frequency.

Answer (score -2):

Schrödinger joked about that: "If I smoke 25 cigarettes per day, and my wife smokes 10, and my daughter 12 - is not the
family consumption 47 per day-on the average?" (The British Journal for the Philosophy of Science, Vol. 3, No. 10 (Aug., 1952), pp. 109-123).

My take is as follows (I will use the example of wave vector, rather than frequency): for particle diffraction and interference, the momentum transfer is defined by Fourier components of matter distribution in the crystal lattice / diffraction grating / screen (see Duane, W., PNAS 1923, 9, 158; Epstein, P.S.; Ehrenfest, P., PNAS 1924, 10, 133; Landé, A., The British Journal for the Philosophy of Science 1965, XV, 307.), so the mass of the incident particle plays a "passive" role: for the same momentum transfer, the effective de Broglie wavelength is shorter for a particle of a larger mass.

Comment: This does not answer my question.